# создать новую ссылку для ссылочной переменной

Tags: python

Подскажите, как создать новую ссылку для ссылочной переменной "a" в цикле? При таком коде значения всех полей списка res будут значения последней записи в records. Новую переменную создаю. Вопрос вроде бы простой, не но пойму как правильно сделать.

```py
from Models.User import User

        for row in records:
            a = User
            a.user_id = row[0]
            a.name = row[1]
            a.surname = row[2]
            a.register_datetime = row[3]
            a.login = row[4]
            a.rate = row[5]
            res.append(a)


class User:
    user_id = 0
    surname = ""
    name = ""
    register_datetime = ""
    login = ""
    rate = 0

    def __init__(self, user_id, person_id, surname, name, register_datetime, login, rate):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.person_id = person_id
        self.surname = surname
        self.name = name
        self.register_datetime = register_datetime
        self.login = login
        self.rate = rate
```

Comment: Новую ссылку? `b = a`

Comment: Проблема тут, похоже, в том, что бы не создаете объект класса User, а создаете ссылку на него.
Замените a = User на a = User().

Comment: @n1tr0xs а это может не сработать, потому что из вопроса в текущем его виде мы не знаем, что такое User, какие аргументы принимает его \_\_init\_\_ и есть ли он вообще

Comment: Ну а теперь, если у класса User всё-таки есть функция \_\_init\_\_, то нет никакого смысла городить все эти `a.user_id = блаблабла` ведь можно просто передать всё в конструктор

Comment: Правда, откуда должен взяться `person_id`, не очень понятно, потому что внутри цикла такого нет

Comment: Решено. Да, person_id лишний, и класс не правильно объявил. Без скобок не срабатывало.

Comment: Ну и да, объявление `user_id = 0` и прочих значений внутри класса тоже имеет мало смысла, если \_\_init\_\_ их тоже задаёт из аргументов

Comment: Вам бы разобраться, что такое переменные класса (или статические переменные в других языках это может называться) и переменные **экземпляра** класса. Вы всё валите в кучу, пока не разберётесь, будете блуждать в потёмках.